# "stop the task if it runs longer than X day" not working

Tags: task-scheduler

I Create a Task Scheduler via GPO to do a job.
I set task to stop running after 3 days and delete after 30 days, but it’s not working.
Task running every day.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGs21.png)

```
  <TaskV2 clsid="{D8896631-B747-47a7-84A6-C155337F3BC8}" name="Foxit_Reader_user_regedit" image="2" changed="2017-05-23 10:49:32" uid="{60E582A9-13CA-4898-BE13-FC9F9BCA6D62}" userContext="0" removePolicy="0">
        <Properties action="U" name="Foxit_Reader_user_regedit" runAs="%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%" logonType="InteractiveToken">
            <Task version="1.3">
                <RegistrationInfo>
                    <Author>*****\****</Author>
                    <Description></Description>
                </RegistrationInfo>
                <Principals>
                    <Principal id="Author">
                        <UserId>%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%</UserId>
                        <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
                        <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
                    </Principal>
                </Principals>
                <Settings>
                    <IdleSettings>
                        <Duration>PT5M</Duration>
                        <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
                        <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
                        <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
                    </IdleSettings>
                    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
                    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
                    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
                    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
                    <AllowStartOnDemand>false</AllowStartOnDemand>
                    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
                    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
                    <Priority>7</Priority>
                    <DeleteExpiredTaskAfter>P30D</DeleteExpiredTaskAfter>
                </Settings>
                <Triggers>
                    <LogonTrigger>
                        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                        <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
                        <StartBoundary>2017-05-04T07:11:53</StartBoundary>
                        <EndBoundary>3000-05-04T07:11:53</EndBoundary>
                    </LogonTrigger>
                </Triggers>
                <Actions Context="Author">
                    <Exec>
                        <Command>%systemroot%\regedit.exe</Command>
                        <Arguments>/s \\hoyer.local\sysvol\hoyer.local\scripts\Foxit_Reader\user.reg</Arguments>
                    </Exec>
                </Actions>
            </Task>
        </Properties>
        <Filters>
            <FilterFile bool="AND" not="1" path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" type="EXISTS" folder="0"/>
            <FilterRunOnce hidden="1" not="0" bool="AND" id="{803FE6D4-0287-463B-834A-04E3B1B3D71B}"/>  </Filters></TaskV2>
```

Comment: Did you read the boundary end date??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `EndBoundary` date to the year 3000; that is not 30 days from now.

Comment: Yes. i did.
without a expire date, I can’t checkbox "if the task is not scheduled to run again delete it after"
What I want ?
I want Task Scheduler stop running after X day and be delete it after X day.
Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question. In this case, I personally would create a second job that deletes the first one with `schtasks /delete <arg>` and run it once when the job is done.

Comment: Date of employment are diffrenet, i have to make Task Scheduler to delete himself after x days or runs.

Maybe i should make a powershell to do that ?

Comment: Yes, the script (regardless if PowerShell, batch or whatever) can remove it's entry by itself.